# Having cors issue during MERN Web App deployment to cpanel, but worked locally

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, cors

I have tried every solution, switching from mongoose to mongoDB, using a manual cors, and debugging by removing line by line and finally finding out that what caused my app to encounters CORS issue is my mongoDB connection.
Even just a simple mongoose or mongoDB definition without actually using them still caused cors issue.
It worked fine on the development server hosted locally.

Below doesn't work

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongo url";

// const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
//   serverApi: {
//     version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
//     strict: true,
//     deprecationErrors: true,
//   }
// });

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested, Content-Type, Accept Authorization"
    )
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE"
      )
      return res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next()
  })
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        name: "Code Bless You",
        Subscribe: true,
    });

});

app.listen(5200, () => console.log("Server is running on port 5200"));
```

This worked

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
// const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongo url";

// const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
//   serverApi: {
//     version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
//     strict: true,
//     deprecationErrors: true,
//   }
// });

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested, Content-Type, Accept Authorization"
    )
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE"
      )
      return res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next()
  })
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        name: "Code Bless You",
        Subscribe: true,
    });

});

app.listen(5200, () => console.log("Server is running on port 5200"));
```

Tried every solution I could find both on random google websites and on stackoverflow.
for reference, here is how I am using fetch throughout the frontend
App.jsx

```
  const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState(null);

  const handleCorsTest = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://api.siperjaka.cloud');
      setResponseData(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('CORS Test Error:', error);
    }
  };
<button onClick={handleCorsTest}>Test CORS</button>
```

[Error] Origin https://siperjaka.cloud is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 500
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.siperjaka.cloud/ due to access control checks.
[Error] CORS Test Error:
D

code: "ERR_NETWORK"

config: {transitional: {silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}, adapter: ["xhr", "http"], transformRequest: Array, transformResponse: Array, timeout: 0, …}

message: "Network Error"

name: "AxiosError"

request: XMLHttpRequest {listeners: Object, onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, …}

stack: "D@https://siperjaka.cloud/assets/index-aAE4spmR.js:40:147904↵@https://siperjaka.cloud/assets/index-aAE4spmR.js:42:162726"

D Prototype
(anonymous function) (index-aAE4spmR.js:44:172337)
asyncFunctionResume
(anonymous function)
promiseReactionJobWithoutPromise
promiseReactionJob
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://siperjaka.cloud is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 500 (api.siperjaka.cloud, line 0)

Comment: the internal server error (500) is probably occurring before any of the code you've shown gets a chance to run, therefore the CORS headers won't be issued - you need to find the root cause of the 500 error

Comment: by the way, why do you "manually" send CORS headers AND use `app.use(cors());`?

Comment: also, what does `https://api.siperjaka.cloud` have to do with YOUR server running on port 5200 in some undisclosed domain?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this. Am i not supposed to use port to run my server? 
https://api.siperjaka.cloud, it's the url to my backend app.

Comment: That answers my question the fact that `https://api.siperjaka.cloud` is your server - now, it's running on port 5200 ... so how does `axios.get('https://api.siperjaka.cloud')` manage to get to port 5200?